# Android screen size for mockup

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

I have a project and I need to do a mockup of an app on adobe illustrator, it's an android app, but I am unsure which screen size (in pixels) should I design it for? According to http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html Normal mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi are the most popular, but I am not sure what that means in terms of making a mockup (I need a definitive width and height to make the mockups)?

Comment: you might wanna check resolution of popular android devices for your mockups. I think that'll do.

Comment: The screen size you can define based on for which device you want to application to develop. Also for which resolutions devices do you want to provide a compatibility of your application.

Comment: From normal sized up to XLarge and from Android 2.3+

Comment: @VishwasSharma Anything?